# La columna requerida no estaba presente en los resultados de una operación 'FromSql'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy intentado hacer un inner join en entity framework de la siguiente manera

```
public  ICollection GetInnerJoin(int idBanco,int idmodelo)
{
    ICollection<Modelo> modelo = _modeRepo.GetModelo(idmodelo);
    string columns = "";
    int cont = 0;
    foreach (var modelcol in modelo)
    {
        if (cont == modelo.Count-1)
        {
            columns = columns + "columna" + modelcol.columnadestino;
        }
        else
        {
            columns = columns + "columna" + modelcol.columnadestino + ",";
        }
        cont++;
    }
    //var conn = _db.Database.GetDbConnection();
    //conn.Open();
    //var command = conn.CreateCommand();
    //string query = "select banco.banco, banco.descripcion, banco.numeroCuenta," + columns + " from ModeloBanco inner join Banco on banco.idBanco=ModeloBanco.idBanco where ModeloBanco.idBanco=" + Convert.ToString(idBanco);
    //command.CommandText = query;
    //var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    //while (reader.Read())
    //{
    //    var title = reader.GetString(0);
    //    Do whatever you want with title
    //}
    //string sql= "select * from ModeloBanco inner join Banco on banco.idBanco=ModeloBanco.idBanco where ModeloBanco.idBanco=" + Convert.ToString(idBanco);
    string sql = "select banco.banco, banco.descripcion, ModeloBanco.idregistro ,banco.numeroCuenta," + columns + " from ModeloBanco inner join Banco on banco.idBanco=ModeloBanco.idBanco where ModeloBanco.idBanco=" + Convert.ToString(idBanco);
    return _db.ModeloBanco.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList();
}
```

Sin embargo me sale este error:

> The required column 'micolumna' was not present in the results of a
> 'FromSql' operation.'

He estado buscando y me he topado con que el modelo con se está mapeando la consulta no coincide con los resultados que trae desde el sql server, pero yo necesito que mi consulta sea dinámica, o sea, que no siempre voy a traer la misma cantidad de columnas.

Agradecería si alguien pudiera ayudarme

Comment: Sin ofender, primero deberias limpiar el codigo para que sea mas corto y concizo el problema a leer, todo lo comentado deberias sacarlo si no es relevante para la pregunta, por otro lado no estas haciendo un join con Entity Framework, lo estas haciendo en sql, y parece que la columna que le estas pasando no existe. Tampoco se sabe que te trae GetModelo

Comment: Listo compadre Muchísimas gracias, intentaré mejorar mi pregunta. Saludos :D